# How to Start a timer in other form in C#

Tags: c#, forms, timer

I have 2 forms and what I want to do is when I click a button in Form2, a timer in Form1 starts

How can i do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a constructor to `Form2`, that takes a `Timer` as parameter:

```
private Timer _timer;
public Form2(Timer timer) 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _timer = timer;
}
```

When you opening your second form from `Form1` use this constructor instead of parameterless constructor and pass the Timer:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(yourTimerInForm1);
f2.Show();
```

Then all you need to do it `_timer.Start()` in your button click event in `Form2`.